# Udev is creating too many devices

Tags: linux, udev

I have built a kernel and root file system for a vortexS86 processor using OpenEmbedded.  When it comes up I have hundreds of device entries in the `/dev` directory.  This include such items as:

```
digi_ctl(0-255)
pty(a-z)(0-f)
ttyD(0-255)
ttyMX(0-255)
..etc
```

I am trying to figure out whether udev is creating all of these and if so where.  If it isn't udev - where are they coming from?

I can find no rules under either `/lib/udev/rules.d` or `/etc/udev/rules.d` that contain any reference the device types.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe device drivers can create device files in /dev/ without there needing to be udev rules for them, espectially ptys and ttys and stuff.

Are these files bothering you for some reason or are you just wanting to keep /dev sparse, I'm sure you can tell udev NOT to create the default entries. use something like:

```
udevinfo -q all -n /path/to/device
```

to find out more info about it